# Is there a proper name for a "coming soon" website?

Tags: terminology

I know it is a simple question, but I failed to google it, or the answer is simply "no".

A "coming soon" site is a page that keeps on the domain while the actual page is developed. There are examples of it on [hongkiat](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/coming-soon-page-design-with-examples), and those pages can be done on wordpress with [ultimate coming soon page plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-coming-soon-page/).

Is there any proper way to call those pages? Or it is usual calling it  "coming soon page"?

Comment: I call it the "Thing which haunts me at night until it's removed."

Comment: Use the Wayback Machine to see the first snapshots of websites. I think the best initial pages are public beta versions. Others contain teasers, about, address or direct you to a post with additional info: http://web.archive.org/web/20080703183923/http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: To help us answer the question better, perhaps you want to clarify the type of content or information (or the lack of) that is normally presented on these pages. I think there might be a few different variations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Landing Page
- Coming Soon Page
- Pre-launch / Pre Launch / Launching Soon Page

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Ryan's suggestions, I also like "Holding Page" or "Placeholder Page."

Answer (score 2):

I think there are a couple of different names, but it generally depends on the type of content that is presented on the page.

In my opinion, if it is just an empty page with a title and some pretty/cute graphics then a 'Coming Soon' is appropriate because there's nothing else to go on.

If there is some detail about when the page will be launched (usually be using a count down of some sort), then a 'Launch Countdown' page is probably more informative.

If there is some interactive element that also engages the user, or captures email or subscription details, then I think a 'Pre-Launch Teaser' page will give you an idea of what it is about.

And there are still probably lots of different variations/combinations, but hopefully this is a more accurate answer.